# Element in the header is not align by flexbox why? here are some conditions I has to follow

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

Conditions

1. I can't change anything in the HTML file.
2. I can only use flexbox to do that.

**The final result**
[image]

**Current condition**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<header>
      <h1><a href="index.html">Super Legit News</a></h1>
      <h2><a href="index.html">Where fake news are born!</a></h2>
      <div id="signup">
        <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        <a href="login.html">Login</a>
      </div>
</header>
```

In **CSS** I Just tried that after that I try some other properties but did not get the restult

```
body>header{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header>div{
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

**After adding CSS**
[image]

I think I missing something in using flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `flex-flow: row wrap;`

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 30px;
}
header h1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#signup {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <h1><a href="index.html">Super Legit News</a></h1>
      <h2><a href="index.html">Where fake news are born!</a></h2>
      <div id="signup">
        <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        <a href="login.html">Login</a>
      </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't really post that much infos, I can't give you an extremely accurate answer. But this is the solution I came up with. I also took away the `<h2>` tag, as it now looks more like the picture you posted. Basically the solution would be to add a wrapper around the bottom row.

```css
#lower {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <h1><a href="index.html">Super Legit News</a></h1>
      <div id="lower">
        <a>Where fake news are born!</a>
        <div id="signup">
          <a href="register.html">Register</a>
          <a href="login.html">Login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

Comment: but I can't change anything in the HTML

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. Sorry mate